# How are whiskers in a Boxplot of different lengths?

Tags: median, boxplot, interquartile

The formula for calculating the position of the whiskers is

Q3+1.5IQR  and Q1-1.5IQR

But doesn't that mean that the length of the whiskers should be of the same length? How are they of different lengths in some boxplots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily. The whiskers actually end at the highest point within $Q3+1.5R$ and at the lowest point above $Q1-1.5R$. So for instance if $Q3+1.5R=100$ and the highest value in your sample is $90$ then the whisker will end at $90$. You must be observing something like this.

Comment: Okay so the line at both whiskers end depending on the data points in our sample?

Comment: Yes but if there are points above Q3+1.5R then it will end at Q3+1.5R otherwise at the maximum value below that. That is why if there are points above Q3+1.5R and below Q1-1.5R then the length of the whiskers look the same.